# Bloomberg zero rate calculation using shift

Tags: interest-rates, bloomberg, spot-rate

I used Bloomberg to calculate a zero rate under a parallel shift of 100 basis points, however I can not understand the results neather duplicate them. I included the +100 basis points by using the shift column.

[image: Bloomberg screenshot].

The 3M is a money market rate, all other rates are swap

Comment: What command in Bloomberg do you use?

Comment: I included a screen shot. I added the +100 basis points manually by typing 100 in the shift field (above the shift column)